# In-Context Express Checkout - Is MerchantID mandatory?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm wrapping up my express checkout integration. So far, so good. Only possible problem is I need to supply MerchantID in paypal.checkout.setup(..), something like this was not needed in classic EC. Because I'm implementing on an ecommerce system with many stores, but same code, this presents a bit of a struggle.
What I noticed is that if I simply put an empty string for ID, the checkout process completes successfully on sandbox.

My fairly short question is how mandatory is that ID, since it's only needed for In-Context checkout and practically any string works? Can I skip it?

Thanks!

Comment: glad someone already asked this. the docs for in-context ID are so frustratingly bad. people writing documentation need to answer basic obvious questions like yours and PayPal fails miserably in that respect. there is no reason whatsoever for the merchant ID to be put in the Javascript except perhaps to track failed popups. is it a security issue? not sure, but I for one don't want my merchant ID sitting out there in Javascript waiting to be used against me by someone trying to break into my account

Answer (score 1):

The field is not exactly mandatory. You are not required to put in your email address or your Merchant ID. It's used for tracking with PayPal using In-Context. However, in order to generate the button you will need to keep a space in the field.

paypal.checkout.setup(' ', {
           container: 'myContainer',
           environment: 'production'
});

Comment: did you get this information from an authoritative source? i.e. is there any chance that suddenly one day this will break?